# Poco c++ Linking Error : undefined reference to `Poco::Data::MySQL::Connector::registerConnector()

Tags: c++, mysql, ubuntu, poco-libraries

I successfully built and installed POCO C++ using these steps: https://pocoproject.org/docs/00200-GettingStarted.html

I ran the following commands during build:

```
sudo apt-get install openssl libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libiodbc2 libiodbc2-dev 
Installed Mysql client 
gunzip poco-X.Y.tar.gz
tar -xf poco-X.Y.tar
cd poco-X.Y
./configure
make -s -j4
```

The build was successful.

For installation:

```
./configure --prefix==/usr/local/poco2/
sudo make -s install
```

My `testy.cpp` code:

```
#include "iostream.h"
#include "Poco/Data/MySQL/MySQLException.h"
#include "Poco/Data/MySQL/MySQL.h"
#include "Poco/Data/MySQL/Connector.h"
#include "Poco/Data/SessionFactory.h"

using namespace Poco::Data;

int main() {
    MySQL::Connector::registerConnector();

    return 0;
}
```

My error is :

> /tmp/ccvlAI5T.o: In function `main':
>
> testy.cpp:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `Poco::Data::MySQL::Connector::registerConnector()'
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Include paths:

```
-I/home/saurabh/project2/poco-1.7.9-all/Data/MySQL/include/
-I/usr/local/poco2/include/
-I/usr/include
```

Linked paths:

```
-L/usr/local/poco2/lib/
-L/home/saurabh/project2/poco-1.7.9-all/lib/Linux/x86_64
-L/usr/lib -lmysqlclient
```

The compile and execute command on Ubuntu Linux is:

```
g++ -o testy testy.cpp -I/home/saurabh/project2/poco-1.7.9-all/Data/MySQL    /include/  -I/usr/local/poco2/include/  -I/usr/include -L/usr/local/poco2    /lib  -L/home/saurabh/project2/poco-1.7.9-all/lib/Linux/x86_64 -L/usr/lib     -lmysqlclient
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to link with **libPocoDataMysql**.
In my setup, this command is enough to compile and link without error:

```
g++ -o testy testy.cpp -I/usr/include/c++/7/ -lPocoDataMySQL
```

Add the correct include and library paths, if needed.

Comment: Hi Thanks, it compiled and linked